# Issue with dual-booting Linux Mint and Mac OS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have a 2013 Macbook Pro that I recently installed Linux Mint on with the intention of dual booting. I've followed all the steps and have rEFInd Boot Manager installed. Mint has been loading up just fine, then I went into `efibootmgr` to change the bootorder. The original output of `efibootmgr` was:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080,0081
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

I called `sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0000,0081` to have Mac OS load up first, since that's where rEFInd is installed (as far as I understand). The rEFInd boot screen appears when restarted, but there is no option for Mac OS. And now I'm getting some strange information, this is after two attempts at setting the bootorder:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0080,0081
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* O瑰污Ȩ
Boot0002* O瑰污Ȩ
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

It appears that a new boot option(?) with unusual characters shows up each attempt. Not exactly sure what is going on here, and I'm hoping I didn't corrupt my Mac OS. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Google Translate says "瑰污Ȩ" is Chinese and translates it to "Rosette". Have you tried any of the new entries?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Oh weird, no I haven't. Pretty hesitant to do anything I'm unsure of at this point.

Comment: As an update to myself, it appears that `BootFFFF` is actually the partition that Mac OS is on. I was able to get into Mac OS Disk Utility and found the Mac OS partition was type `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`, after some searching around, I will attempt to solve this with solutions found on this thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239759/partition-type-suddenly-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-drive-unmountable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was removing the Chinese character boot entry and manually re-adding refind as a boot entry.

Here are the commands that I used. Be sure to adapt them for your situation and take care to change the boot numbers in the commands to match your system.

```
efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries.

sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
sudo efibootmgr -b 0002 -B
#remove all of the Chinese character boot options. For you the boot numbers appear to be 0001 and 0002.

sudo nautilus /boot/efi
#this helped me determine the file path for refind on my system. In my case it was /boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi

df -h
#view all of your system partitions. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi

sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L refind -l /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi
#you can type "man efibootmgr" for more information. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi and put the number of that partition after the -p option.

efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries. In my case refind was 0000 and ubuntu was 0001.

sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0001
```

For more information:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples